# How to modify the form filed data?

Tags: django, modelform, cleaned-data

I have a model:

```
class PastStudy(Model):
    grade_average = FloatField(null=True)
```

I have a modelform as below:

```
class PastStudyForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = PastStudy
        fields = ('grade_average', )
```

What I have in view:

```
...
if request.POST:
    past_study_form = PastStudyForm(request.POST)

    if past_study_form.is_valid():
        return HttpResponse(past_study_form.cleaned_data['grade_average'])

else:
    profile_filter_past_study_form = ProfileFilterPastStudyForm()
...
```

What I need is that I want to write a clean method for PastStudyForm so that in case I entered 90 as grade average, HttpResponse converts it two 0-20 grading scheme and returns 18. 
I tried this and I was still getting 90 not 18

```
class PastStudyForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = PastStudy
        fields = ('grade_average', )

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        grade_average = self.cleaned_data['grade_average']
        self.cleaned_data['grade_average'] = grade_average/5
        return cleaned_data
```

and This:

```
class PastStudyForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = PastStudy
        fields = ('grade_average', )

    def clean_grade_average(self):
        grade_average = self.cleaned_data['grade_average']
        data = grade_average/5
        return data
```

However, I still get 90. I also have tried a few other methods but I still was getting 90 in HttpResponse

Maybe using clean method be wrong and I should do something else!

The real code is huge and I have summarized it in here and other aspects of the problem are not explained in here. That is why I prefer and expect to get a response in which I am advised how to it in the form definition, not other methods such as converting it in the view.

Comment: What happens if you return the `past_study_form` in your response, and then in the template write `past_study_form.grade_average`? Same result?

Comment: I do not have a template for request.POST . I am returning it as an HttpResponse. Please stick to this situation and tell what to write in the HttpResponse to test and let you know what will be the result

Answer (score 1):

in your `clean` method, you assign the result of your calculation method into `self.cleaned_data`,
while you are returning `cleaned_data` not `self.cleaned_data`.
it is different variable.

try this instead:

```
self.cleaned_data = super().clean()
grade_average = self.cleaned_data['grade_average']
self.cleaned_data['grade_average'] = grade_average/5
return self.cleaned_data
```

Comment: It did not work and I am still getting the same result as before

Comment: It seems that clean method is irrelevant to this situation. I found this in the documentation:
Form.clean()
Implement a clean() method on your Form when you must add custom validation for fields that are interdependent. See Cleaning and validating fields that depend on each other for example usage.